# Chrome45 and Firefox - ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION on most of the sites

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, https

I have started receiving this error when I visit most of the sites - 
Microsoft sites incl. MSDN knowledge base, Lynda.com etc.

> SSL server probably obsolete. ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION
>   Unable to connect securely to the server. This website may have worked
>   previously, but there is a problem with the server. Connecting to such
>   sites weakens security for all users and thus has been disabled.

Is there any way I could override this. I am using Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m and Firefox v.40.0.3 Works fine on the fabled IE...sigh

Comment: These sites work find from here with both of these browsers (same version). Might there be some firewall or local security solution which tries to intercept SSL connections and thus causes them too break?

Answer (score 3):

Lets understand step by step

**POODLE Attack :**

A POODLE attack is an exploit that takes advantage of the way some browsers deal with encryption. POODLE (Padding Oracle On Downgraded Legacy Encryption) is the name of the vulnerability that enables the exploit.

**SSL 3 is dead, killed by the POODLE attack:**

https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/10/15/ssl-3-is-dead-killed-by-the-poodle-attack

https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-290A

**How to check for SSL POODLE / SSLv3 bug on WebLogic? How to fix**

**SSL and Weblogic - Remote PSAdmin**

http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2014/10/16/check-ssl-poodle-sslv3-bug-weblogic-fix/

http://remotepsadmins.com/2015/01/24/ssl-weblogic/

**Chrome set to disable and remove SSLv3 in upcoming releases

http://www.zdnet.com/article/chrome-set-to-disable-and-remove-sslv3-in-upcoming-releases/

**How to fix issue :**

Upgrade certificate

**Work around :**

**POODLE Disabling SSLv3 Support in Browsers**

https://zmap.io/sslv3/browsers.html

```
For Google Chrome:

1) Create new shortcut for your Chrome on your desktop

(2) Right click and select properties

(3) Look for Shortcut tab and add the following start-up parameter (Target field):

--cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0039,0x0033

Example: 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0039,0x0033

4) Click Apply and open your browser from Shortcut

You can also run above line from command window to open Google Chrome.

For Firefox:


(1) In a new tab, type or paste about:config in the address bar and press Enter. 

(2) In the search box above the list, type or paste dhe and pause while the list is filtered

(3) Double-click the security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha preference to switch it from true to false 

(4) Double-click the security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha preference to switch it from true to false 

(5) Restart your browser
```

Comment: I don't think this is relevant. Already checked this one, was way back in 2014

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it happens only for you, and for various common sites, indicates that your traffic is being modified by a proxy or an antivirus program that is misconfigured regardless of what site it's intercepting.
You should probably figure out what it is, and update it/find an alternative.

Comment: hmmm, seems weird, its at my workplace.
Works fine on opera / safari / IE

Not on the latest chrome / firefox

Comment: yea... Its chrome and firefox; some type of weird arrogance where their engineering and DEVs are pushing forced security to end users; extremely annoying for embedded devices that can't be updated.  Someone needs to tell them to get off their high horse and make usability priority over security...